# ORA-00936:missing expression error

Tags: loops, cursor, procedure, ora-00936

Error I am getting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yYqj.jpg)

The error is thrown on 'insert' statements in the procedure. The target table has the same number of columns and datatype, as in the insert statement.

**My procedure is:**

```
create or replace procedure updatetax
is
date_30 date:=sysdate-(365*30);
date_50 date:=sysdate-(365*50);
/*employees less than 30 years of age*/
cursor c1 is
select eid
from employee 
where dateofbirth>date_30
and enddate is null;
/*employees between the age of 30 and 50*/
cursor c2 is
select eid
from employee
where dateofbirth between date_50 and date_30;
/*employees greater than 50 years of age*/
cursor c3 is
select eid
from employee
where dateofbirth<date_50;
r1 employee.eid%type;
r2 employee.eid%type;
r3 employee.eid%type;
begin
  open c1;
  for r1 in c1
  loop
    insert into emptax
    values(r1.eid,gettaxlessthan30(select salary from empsalary where eid=r1.eid),sysdate);
  end loop;
  close c1;
  commit;
  open c2;
  for r2 in c2
  loop
    insert into emptax
    values(r2.eid,gettaxbetween30and50(select salary from empsalary where eid=r2.eid),sysdate);
  end loop;
  commit;
  open c3;
  close c2;
  for r3 in c3
  loop
    insert into emptax
    values(r3.eid,gettaxgreaterthan50(select salary from empsalary where eid=r3.eid),sysdate);
  end loop;
  commit;
  close c3;
end;
/
```

**The functions called in the stored procedure are of the below logic:**

```
create or replace function gettaxlessthan30(esalary_in number)
return number
is
  tax_out number(10,2);
begin
  tax_out:=0.07*esalary_in;
  return tax_out;  
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved - rewrote the procedure again from start and it worked just fine.